# Php query to display number of sql results being shown

Tags: php, mysql, count

Hi I have the following code to display all the golf courses within County Antrim:

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("golf_locate") or die(mysql_error());
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM golf_courses WHERE county = 'Antrim'")
or die(mysql_error());

$image = "golfimage.jpg";

while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))
{
Echo "<div id='image'><img src=".$image.">" . "<br />" . "</div>";
Echo "<div id='text'>";
Echo "Golf Club:&nbsp;" . $info["club_name"] . "<br />";
Echo "County:&nbsp;" . $info["county"] . "<br />";
Echo "To read more information on this golf club and course " . $info["description"];
Echo "</div>";
}

?>
```

Could anyone tell me the query that I could use before it to display the number of results being shown. For example "Showing 38 golf clubs in this County" - but result being counted using php?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this

```
   $count = mysql_num_rows($data);

   echo "Showing ". $count. " golf clubs in this County";
```

Comment: It is saying this: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'

Where should I put that piece of code? Sorry new to php so not too sure what i'm even doing lol.

Comment: @StudentNeedingHelp I have updated code forgot to add '.' check now

Comment: Yes its working sort of, but saying repeatedly "Showing 1 golf clubs in this County", but there is 38 golf clubs showing. Is that because of the array I have it in?

Comment: $count =  count($data );
$image = "golfimage.jpg";

echo "Showing" . $count . "golf clubs in this County";

while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))
{
echo "<div id='image'><img src=".$image.">" . "<br />" . "</div>";


etc

Comment: may be try mysql_num_rows($data) instead of count($data) once

Comment: Got it working with this: $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($data);

echo "$num_rows Rows\n";

thanks so much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think `mysql_num_rows($resource)` will do it. Is this what you were asking for?

Comment: I'll try that now, not even exactly sure what i'm asking for, new to php so just trying to figure my way out around different things. Thanks :)